# How to allow Mysql to add more than 1000 rows?

Tags: mysql

I have installed Mysql on vista and XP. I use perl to crawl the net and insert the data needed into mysql database. The problem is that once the database reaches 1000 rows, the script is not anymore able to add data into the database. is there something that I have to do to fix that problem? I expect the database to have more than 80,000 rows. Thanks for your help.

Comment: One thing you have to do is post an error message and some code.

Comment: Er, what kind of error do you get when you try to insert?

Comment: What error is it reporting? How's the database layout?

Comment: after 1000 rows, the script keeps running, there is no error message at all. But I just notice that even if the script is still running, once i have reached 1000 rows, no more rows are added into the database.

Comment: This is a guess, but it could be to do with your primary key field having a length of 3! If you run `DESCRIBE table_name` you can see the structure of your table. However, I could be totally off the mark!

Comment: Um, what kind of program are you using? MySQL Workbench and SQL Manager will limit the query output to 1000 rows by default.

Comment: my primary key was define like this: int not null primary key auto_increment,

Comment: I use MySQL Workbench and MySQL Server 5.5

Comment: Run `SELECT COUNT(*) from table_name`, what do you get?

Comment: when running SELECT COUNT(*) from table_name, I got : LIMIT 0, 1000

Comment: I also got the error:" Error Code:1046. No database selected. Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking its name in the SCHEMAS listed in the sidebar." I followed those instruction, and run again count(*), and it showed 3044.

Comment: Then there are 3,044 rows in your database. You're confusing how many rows some software you're using is showing you at a time, versus how many are actually in the database. You will not run into any kind of limit until you have billions of rows.

Comment: How to set up the workbench to actually displays the exact amount of rows currently present in the database at anytime?

Comment: never mind, I found it!  I clicked on the icon which says "toggle limitation of the records number" and it shows all the 3040 current rows. Thanks to all of you for your help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The MySQL Workbench will by default show just 1000 rows to prevent you from loading the whole table (which will require loads of time once you reach lets say 2million records).

On the screenshot you can see the controls which are placed directly over the resultset. If you want to display all data, just click the 7th button (Tooltip: Toggle limitation of the records number). This will show you all the records in the table.
[image]

Now in Workbench 6.2 version Go To Query Tab --> Limit Rows --> (Tick Mark) Don't Limit

Answer (score 8):

.

Couldn't you just use something like: SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0, 81000

If you suspect that there are 80k records then this will return all

.

Comment: Great comment, since most of the time I wouldn't want to change the default to don't limit.  This way there's always a way to get the results unlimited without changing the default.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Sequel Pro > Preferences > Tables > Limit result to: (in this case 80,000) rows

Answer (score 0):

You can select number of rows in Mysql Workbench by clicking the dropdown as shown below:

[image]

Or you can go to Edit -> Preferences -> SQL Editor -> SQL Execution and set the limit on Limit Rows Count.